# groovy: how to simplify/rewrite this method in groovy

Tags: groovy

```
protected int xMethod (Integer a, Integer b) {
  if (a<b)
    return 1
  else if (a>b)
    return 2
  else
    return 3
}
```

I wonder if there is some way of rewriting above method differently in groovy? as now is very Java style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the function just needs to return 3 different values depending on whether a is less than, equal to, or greater than b. There is already an operator in Groovy that does this:

```
a <=> b
```

The return values are -1, 0 and 1. Perhaps the best thing to do is refactor the code to use this operator instead of xMethod, if that is possible.

Of course, if the precise values 1, 2 and 3 are important and not just 3 distinct values then you can't do this.

Comment: @Mark Byers - OK, what will my method look like if I change my return values to -1, 0, 1? many thanks

Comment: @Sapo: You could do that, or you could just scrap the xMethod entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on Mark's answer:

```
protected int xMethod (Integer a, Integer b) {
    switch ( a <=> b ) {
       case -1: 1; break
       case  1: 2; break
       case  0: 3; break
    }
}
```

However, you have to question whether this method has any value. If the caller can be changed to accept -1, 0, 1 then the method has no reason to exist.

Answer (score 0):

How about:
 `return (a <=> b) + 2`

Comment: This maps `-1, 0, 1` to `1, 2, 3`, but he needs it to go `1, 3, 2`. You can work out the formula so that it gets the values he wants, but I don't think it's worth the complication.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the two occurrences of Integer from the signature, you can call the method with any parameters for which < is defined.

E.g.

assert x.xMethod(1, 2)==1 
assert x.xMethod("2", "1")==2
assert x.xMethod(2.0, 2.0)==3